# Tooltip bug with dynamic google charts

Tags: javascript, svg, dynamic, charts, timeline

I am using google timeline charts for a project .
The timeline is being updated every some seconds(randomly) adding new lines in the graph .

When the lines are being added to the timeline tooltip pop up does not disappear from the screen when mouse moves over to other lines. The tooltip is sticky on the screen and this gives an unpleasant user experience

Any solution for this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution ,

```
container = document.getElementById('' + youridentifier + '');
chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
chart.draw(dataSet, options);
```

Every time you "redraw" the google chart you have to create a new visualization  object .

Answer (score 0):

If youre using Bootstrap tooltips you can hide them all with a JS call.

```
$(someJQuerySelector).tooltip('hide');
```

Comment: Google has a default tooltip . I use Google's tooltip